# Python - How to Select Certain Lags in ARIMA Model?

Tags: python, arima

I want to fit a model = ARIMA(ret_log, order=(5,0,0)), but with second lag and third lag in AR part set to zero due to non-significant autocorrelation, how can I do it in Python? I know in R it is easily doable.

I've seen similar questions been asked for R, but only one such question be asked for Python([Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55882111/arima-model-for-certain-lags)). However, the answer does not seem to work, nor do I think the person who raised the question was satisfied.

I tried tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.**fix_params** and tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.**fit_constrained**, but both threw out AttributeError, such as 'ARMA' object has no attribute 'fit_constrained'.

Anyone has any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

As mentined in [statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.html) documentation

****p and q may either be integers or lists of integers****
. So you can easily input the lags to include as a list.

Please note that I have not tried it and cannot guarantee that it will work.